# Unity Не работает прыжок

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мучаюсь пару дней. Не работает прыжок. Я довольно таки нуб этой сфере.Прошу помощи. Вот два файла 
Jump.cs(сам прыжок)

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public bool ReadyJump;
    public bool ReadyGround;
    public int ForceJump;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (ReadyJump == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, ForceJump));
            ReadyJump = false;
        }
    }
    public void JumpPlayer()
    {
        ReadyJump = true;

    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            ReadyGround = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ReadyGround = false;
        }
    }
}
```

и файл Run что прицеплен к player

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class Run : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.right * speed);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Process.Start("Jump.cs");
        }
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку, что не может найти файл, хотя оба лежат в одной папке.

Буду очень благодарен, если поможете нубу)

Answer (score 0):

1. Излишнее разбиение классов. Стоит объединить класс Run и Jump и назвать класс Player или PlayerMovement. Это освободит нас от необходимости создавать публичные поля или использовать `Process.Start("Jump.cs");` ведь название класса может измениться что приведёт к ошибке.
2. Прослеживается отсутствие логики в коде, старайтесь больше думать о том что вы пишите, ведь все, даже опытные программисты, допускают ошибки. К примеру `private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)` вызывается только при столкновении, следовательно `ReadyGround = false;` лучше перенести в функцию прыжка ли в OnCollisionExit2D.
3. Пишите всю работу с физикой в FixedUpdate. Т.е. `rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.right * speed);` лучше перенести туда, а прыжок лучше перенести в Update.
4. И главное! Решение чрезвычайно простое значение поля `public bool ReadyJump;` по умолчанию равно false то есть первый прыжок у вас никогда не произойдёт, а значение true ему нигде не присваивается (вы забыли вызывать метод `JumpPlayer`, наличие которого крайне сомнительно)

Comment: `public void JumpPlayer()
    {
        ReadyJump = true;

    }` у меня сразу запускается функция после прыжка. Да, значение ReadyJump со старта false, спасибо.